# Woocommerce paid text appended wrongly

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I noticed in wp-admin, woocommerce order and products tabs, I have "Paid" text prefixed wrongly in many columns. The data itself is not affected, just the display

May I know how to fix this problem?

[image: In products tab]

[image: In orders tab]

Answer (score 0):

> I think you did some customization in Woocommerce source and echo the
>   "Paid" word wrongly.

First you need to search "Paid" word in all your Wordpress source, and base on search result figure out the result, May be chances to there is unnecessary echo this "Paid" word. Also double check your `function.php` file as well.